# Is it necessary to write a return statement in Solidity?

Tags: function, return, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Counter {
    uint public number;
    string public name;

    constructor(string memory input_name, uint input_number){
        name = input_name;
        number = input_number;
    }

    function add () public {
        number ++;
    }

    function subtract() public {
        number --;
    }

    function update_name(string memory update) public {
        name = update;
    }
```

---

I wrote a very basic contract here and I'm wondering why I should write a return statement for each of my functions as it is already returns a value.
Could someone explain my error or the point of the return statement here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solidity have the "implicit return" feature, so as you noticed, you may skip the "return" statement in some cases. However, it's discourages, since you're not explicit enough and may cause a lot of confusion and issues.

For details please check the following links:

- https://medium.com/@pareshmasani/ethereum-smart-contract-implicit-return-can-go-wrong-33b41c93dbba
- https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/3134
- https://blog.openzeppelin.com/instadapp-audit/